# Entity framework migrations. Updating a boolean column to enum

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a production database with a table which have boolean fields as 0,1

Now i need to update the set these fields to enums.

Is this possible? Do i lose data?

I can have correspondig fields to boolean.

I am on my way to airport , i havent tried anything but i m really curious if this can be done.

Comment: how  you supposed to convert these boolean values to enum ?

Comment: Enum is stored as int no? So may be it will accept the conversion.

Comment: which EF version are you using ?

Comment: I am using 6.1......

Comment: If you are careful you can change the type of a column without losing data even if the types are not the same. Just check what the code does in the migration and alter it if necessary. Sometimes you need to add sql to your migration http://stackoverflow.com/a/27925008/150342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just tried this myself using EF 6.1.2:

1) Added a boolean column to a class:

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
        public bool ColumnToConvert { get; set; }
    }
```

2) Generated the corresponding migration:

```
public partial class AddBooleanProperty : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Company", "ColumnToConvert", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Company", "ColumnToConvert");
    }
}
```

3) Insert some rows in the Seed method:

```
        ctx.Companies.AddOrUpdate<Company>(
          c => c.Name,
          new Company { Name = "Company 1", ColumnToConvert = true },
          new Company { Name = "Company 2", ColumnToConvert = false },
          new Company { Name = "Company 3", ColumnToConvert = true }
        );
```

4) Changed the property type from bool to EnumExample:

```
public EnumExample ColumnToConvert { get; set; }
```

where EnumExample is:

```
public enum EnumExample
{
    False,
    True,
    OtherValue,
    AnotherValue
}
```

5) Generated a new migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Company DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Company__ColumnT__47DBAE45"); // Manually added
        AlterColumn("dbo.Company", "ColumnToConvert", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 2));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Company DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Company__ColumnT__47DBAE45");  // Manually added
        AlterColumn("dbo.Company", "ColumnToConvert", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
    }
```

Here I realized that I had to manually drop the DF constraint because when I ran the migration it gave me an error telling me that the column was dependent on the constraint.

6) And then I modified the seed method:

```
ctx.Companies.AddOrUpdate<Company>(
              c => c.Name,
              new Company { Name = "Company 4", ColumnToConvert = EnumExample.AnotherValue },
              new Company { Name = "Company 5", ColumnToConvert = EnumExample.OtherValue },
              new Company { Name = "Company 6", ColumnToConvert = EnumExample.True }
            );
```

RESULT (before and after):

[image: Migrating property from bool to enum]

I hope this helps.

Otherwise, you can always replace the content of your migrations with a script generated by Schema Compare. SC is much more intelligent. It often creates temporal tables to migrate the data, and it handles all the "drop & create constraint" for you.

Comment: I actually did the same and it worked. Thanks for clarifiying.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is an implicit integer so... you can do the conversion without lose data.
Of course, talking about data. If you mapped by any database framework, you´ll have to remap it correctly

Answer (score 0):

`bool` type in C# is not a valid underlying enum type. The smallest type you can use as the underlying type is `byte`. But (AFAIR) `byte` type maps to a `tinyint` and not to `bit` type on the Sql Server side. So first you would have to convert your `bit` column in the database to `tinyint` and then change your model to use an enum whose underlying type is `byte` for the property which is now `bool`. Finally, make sure that the enum values correspond to numbers you have in the database. By default enum values starts from 0 so you should be good without defining values explicitly.